# How to summary two columns into a list

Tags: r

I'm relatively new to R. I don't really know how to phrase this question. Bascically I have two columns in a dataframe like this:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Sample1 | Mutation1 |
| Sample1 | Mutation2 |
| Sample1 | Mutation4 |
| Sample2 | Mutation2 |
| Sample2 | Mutation3 |
| Sample3 | Mutation1 |
| Sample3 | Mutation2 |
| Sample3 | Mutation3 |
| Sample3 | Mutation4 |
| Sample3 | Mutation5 |

And I would to make a list based on those two columns like:

```
$Sample1
[1] "Mutation1" "Mutation2" "Mutation4"

$Sample2
[1] "Mutation2" "Mutation3"

$Sample3
[1] "Mutation1" "Mutation2" "Mutation3" "Mutation4" "Mutation5"
```

The above list is made with:

```
> example_list=list(c("Mutation1", "Mutation2", "Mutation4"), c("Mutation2", "Mutation3"), c("Mutation1", "Mutation2", "Mutation3", "Mutation4", "Mutation5"))
> names(example_list)=c("Sample1", "Sample2", "Sample3")
> example_list
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: See the `split()` function.

Answer (score 0):

This should work I believe

```
complete_dataset <- data.frame(Column.A = c("Sample1", "Sample1", "Sample1", 
                  "Sample2", "Sample2", "Sample3", "Sample3", "Sample3", "Sample3", 
                  "Sample3"),
     Column.B = c("Mutation1", "Mutation2", "Mutation4", 
                   "Mutation2", "Mutation3", "Mutation1", "Mutation2", "Mutation3", 
                   "Mutation4", "Mutation5"))


lapply(split(complete_dataset, complete_dataset['Column.A']), 
       function(sample_data) sample_data$Column.B)
```

- output

```
$Sample1
[1] "Mutation1" "Mutation2" "Mutation4"

$Sample2
[1] "Mutation2" "Mutation3"

$Sample3
[1] "Mutation1" "Mutation2" "Mutation3" "Mutation4" "Mutation5"
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. Using split(complete_dataset$Column.B, complete_dataset$Column.A) also seem to give the same results.